# React Router - tries to load _=_ on redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a node.js application which redirects to http://localhost:8080/ when logged in. This is done using expressJS and looks like this:

`res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/');`

The Developer Tools in Chrome show that it is redirecting as expected as it performs the following:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8080
```

At localhost:8080 there is a react application which uses react-router to handle the routing. The configuration for this looks like the following:

```
const routes = <Route component={AppContainer}>
  <Route path="/" component={DashboardContainer} />
  <Route path="settings" component={SettingsContainer}>
    <Route path="projects" component={ProjectsContainer}>
      <Route path="new" component={NewProject} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="views" component={ViewsContainer}>
      <Route path="new" component={NewView} />
      <Route path=":id" component={EditView} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="themes" component={Themes} />
  </Route>
</Route>;
```

But for some reason the application gets redirected to `http://localhost:8080/#/_=_?_k=1yp57h` which gives `'Warning: [react-router] Location "/_=_" did not match any routes'`

However, if I load http://localhost:8080/ or http://localhost:8080 in my browser directly (skipping out the redirect part) it loads http://localhost:8080/#/?_k=y8p8c9 and the application works fine.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! The authentication process on node.js was integrated with Facebook. It turns out in the callback URL from Facebook it returns a #*=* on the end of the URL, and when I was running `res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/');` it was keeping the hash (didn't think this was how browsers were supposed to work) and was redirecting to `http://localhost:8080/#_=_`

To fix the issue I just forced the hash to be nothing:
`res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/#');`